# Incorrect method suggestion by Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsfilemanager

I am trying to create a directory in my OS X app. The method was suggested as I started typing. But the method seems to be incorrectly suggested. The attributes parameter of the method in NSFileManger normally takes a `[FileAttributeKey:Any]` dictionary, but here in the suggestion it takes a `[String:Any]` library.

I checked the NSFileManager APIs and I could not find any like this. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

[image: incorrect method suggestion]

Comment: you have to use it like FileManager.default.create..... not directly like FileManager.create

Comment: @UmarFarooque .. i know.. fileManager used here is defined as 

**let fileManager = FileManager.default**

Comment: Try to import mobile core service and then pass the keys into the attributes dictionary.

Comment: it is probably the _placeholder_ in the signature has not been updated correctly yet, you still need to pass `[FileAttributeKey:Any]?` as attribute.

Comment: @holex .. I tried passing [FileAttributeKey:Any]?. But got the following error

_Cannot convert value of type '[FileAttributeKey : Date]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]?'_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment target or your Xcode version is old. FileAttributeKey is new.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/fileattributekey